# QT - Increase Richtext size on Button click

Tags: qt

How do i increase the size of a Rich Text on the click of a button ?

I have a [QTextEdit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html) box with Rich text pasted in it.On the click of a + [ui button] i need to increase the font size of all the text inside it. Any idea on how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

This is what you should do inside the slot :

```
//-------------------------desired format------------------------------- 
qreal pointSize = 40; // 40 for example, you can parameterize it
QTextCharFormat format;
format.setFontPointSize(pointSize);
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
ui->textEdit->selectAll(); 
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^ You ask for all text in the textedit
// But remember partially change with mouse selection is also doable
ui->textEdit->mergeCurrentCharFormat(format);
```

(P.S. `ui->textEdit` is a pointer to `QTextEdit`)

The key point is to create an instance of [**`QTextCharFormat`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcharformat.html) to set the "**partial**" information of the font (Ex: size information only) and use [**`QTextEdit::mergeCurrentCharFormat`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#mergeCurrentCharFormat) to merge the original format with the new format.

---

## For example:

After merging by the operations above, the color, font...etc except size will be retained:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `QTestEdit::setCurrentFont()` function. For example:

```
QTextEdit te;
QFont f = te.currentFont();

int oldPointSize = f.pointSize();
int newPointSize = oldPointSize + 10;
f.setPointSize(newPointSize);
te.setCurrentFont(f);

te.setText("Test");
te.show();
```